# R How to convert vectors of number with different length into vectors of binary with fixed length

Tags: r

How to convert this

```
1,2,5,6,9
1,2
3,11
```

into this:

```
1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0
1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
```

I thought I can read my data by adding `na` if the index is not exist.

Then, replace each `na` with zero, and each not `na` with one.
But I don't know how, and I searched to similar code and I didn't find

Comment: Look up the `tabulate` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your original numbers are stored as, but here's a solution assuming it's a list of vectors:

```
nums <-list(
  c(1,2,5,6,9),
  c(1,2),
  c(3,11)
)

maxn <- max(unlist(nums))

lapply(nums, function(x) {
  binary <- numeric(maxn)
  binary[x] <- 1
  binary
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
lapply(z,tabulate,nbins=max(unlist(z)))

[[1]]
 [1] 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0

[[2]]
 [1] 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

[[3]]
 [1] 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

where `z` is a list of vectors:

```
z <- list(c(1,2,5,6,9),c(1,2),c(3,11))
```